# Installing a remote agent Bamboo for Android(based Gradle) Project

Tags: android, gradle, java-8, bamboo

I'm trying to setup an remote agent for Bamboo build system for Gradle based Android project. But problem is Bamboo setup need min Java V1.8 where Gradle could not able to build for Java V1.8. Any suggestion how can configure Bamboo remote agent in this scenario.